# Using pandas applymap() with multiple mapping functions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I am using `df.to_excel()` to output data from a pandas dataframe to excel. To improve readability, I am using `df.style.applymap()` to change the color of the cell based on the contents.

Imagine I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df = 
       Account  Revenue   AccountAge
0     "Boeing"     5000          5.6
1   "Lockheed"   -10000          1.2
2     "Airbus"    12000          0.6
3   "Northrop"    -3000          8.4
```

Where account age represents how long I have had this account on my books. Perhaps I want to flag negative revenue cells as red. I can do:

```
def color_neg_revenue(val):
    if val < 0:
        color = 'red'
    return "background-color: %s" % color

df = df.style.applymap(color_neg_revenue, subset=["Revenue"])
```

I can export this to excel, and the format looks great! But suppose I also want to flag new accounts in yellow, when I try:

```
def color_new_account(val):
    if val < 3:
        color = 'yellow'
    return "background-color: %s" % color

df = df.style.applymap(color_new_account, subset=["AccountAge"])
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'
```

Why can I not use `applymap()` on a dataframe that I have already used `applymap()` on? How can I get around this?

Comment: But you assign the styler to `df`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is not with the function. In your first call you perform:

```
df = df.style.applymap(color_neg_revenue, subset=["Revenue"])
```

So now **`df` is no longer a `DataFrame`, it is a `Styler`**. Such `Styler` has of course no `.style` attribute anymore. You thus better assign it to another variable, and chain on that one. Like:

```
s = df.style.applymap(color_neg_revenue, subset=["Revenue"])

# Look mom, no I have no .style
s = s.applymap(color_new_account, subset=["AccountAge"])
```

You thus can *chain* such `applymap` calls when you use a `Styler`, but such styler has no `.style` attribute itself.

Comment: It still doesn't really work - somehow styles are overwriting each-other